# Specifying machine type for a GCP Dataflow job in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a Dataflow template generated by Dataprep and am executing it using Composer (ie Apache Airflow).

The task is triggering the Dataflow job, but this is then failing with an error which [according to posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309770/diagnosing-failed-cloud-dataflow-pipeline) indicates that I need to specify a machine type with higher memory.

I'm specifying `machineType` in the `DataflowTemplateOperator`, but it's not applying to the Dataflow job:

```
dataflow_default_options={
    'project': 'projectname',
    'zone': 'europe-west1-b',
    'tempLocation': 'gs://bucketname-dataprep-working/temp/',
    'machineType': 'n1-highmem-4'
},
```

Having investigated this for some time, I've seen conflicting advice as to what to call the `machineType` attribute - I've also tried `workerMachineType`, `machine-type` and `worker-machine-type` to no avail.

Has anyone here successfully specified a worker type for `DataflowTemplateOperator`?

Comment: According to [gcp_dataflow_hook.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/16d93c9e45e14179c7822fed248743f0c3fd935c/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py#L275) `machineType` looks to be the variable you want. Sadly though I am not sure why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [hook source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py#L270), `machineType` is the only accepted key for template jobs. The variables you specify are then used to build a request to the REST API, like so:

```py
# RuntimeEnvironment
environment = {}
for key in ['maxWorkers', 'zone', 'serviceAccountEmail', 'tempLocation',
            'bypassTempDirValidation', 'machineType', 'network', 'subnetwork']:
    if key in variables:
        environment.update({key: variables[key]})

# LaunchTemplateParameters
body = {"jobName": name,
        "parameters": parameters,
        "environment": environment}

# projects.locations.template.launch
service = self.get_conn()
request = service.projects().locations().templates().launch(
    projectId=variables['project'],
    location=variables['region'],
    gcsPath=dataflow_template,
    body=body
)
```

The documentation for [`projects.locations.template.launch`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.templates/launch) specifies that the request body should be an instance of [`LaunchTemplateParameters`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/LaunchTemplateParameters), which has another [`RuntimeEnvironment`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/RuntimeEnvironment). This looks to be accurate from the hook source.

Some debugging steps you could take: you could log/inspect the outgoing REST call, or find the call in Stackdriver logging (and therefore metadata related to the job creation request).

Note: This is only available since [[AIRFLOW-1954]](https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/3c5b73579a3e6c8a1e47c2fddf201b99d690bafe), which was part of the Airflow v1.10.0 release. This means it is only present in certain Cloud Composer versions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the Python SDK based on the tag.
Have you tried the Python options from the [execution parameter documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params)? 
The Python option is spelled `machine_type`, which is an alias for `worker_machine_type` with underscores.

I've not used Composer/Airflow before, so this is just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried `machine_type` and `worker_machine_type` but no joy!